# Sorting an array of objects by increasing price

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
for (int i = 0; i < newBookCatalog.length; i++) {
    double currentMin = newBookCatalog[i].getPrice();
    int currentMinIndex = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < newBookCatalog.length; j++) {
        if (currentMin > newBookCatalog[j].getPrice()) {
            currentMin = newBookCatalog[j].getPrice();
            currentMinIndex = j;
        }
    }
    if (currentMinIndex != i) {
        BookCatalog2 temp = newBookCatalog[currentMinIndex];
        newBookCatalog[currentMinIndex] = newBookCatalog[i];
        newBookCatalog[i] = temp;
    }
}
//Display the newly sorted array of objects
for (int i = 0; i < newBookCatalog.length - 1; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-8d%-20s%-19s%-18.2f\n", newBookCatalog[i].getItemNumber(), newBookCatalog[i].getProduct(), newBookCatalog[i].getCategory(), newBookCatalog[i].getPrice());
}
break;
```

This is what i have so far. I'm trying to sort the array by increasing price but when the program runs, it shows all but the last item. I reworked it a few times but i cannot get the sort to show the last item. i'm beginner level and copied the basic structure of the sort from my text book and help from my instructor. The example in my textbook was just for an array of int though. so this was a little bit more complicated.

Any tips or tricks?

Comment: Is this homework?  Is it a requirement that you implement the sorting algorithm yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I reworked it a few times but i cannot get the sort to show the last
>   item.

you're excluding the last item by doing `newBookCatalog.length-1` rather it should be 
`i < newBookCatalog.length`.

change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newBookCatalog.length-1; i++)
```

to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newBookCatalog.length; i++)
```

Comment: @JonBloodworth you're welcome, don't forget to mark as accepted if it has solved your problem  ^^.